# Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables where the probability of success is $1/3$ and the probability of failure is $2/3$.  let $X$ be the number of failures required to obtain the first success.

2nd attempt:

a. What is the distribution of $X$?

It is a geometric distribution since $P(x=N)=(2/3)^N(1/3)$

b. Find $P(4 \le X \le 7)$

$(2/3)^4(1/3)+(2/3)^5(1/3)+(2/3)^6(1/3)+(2/3)^7(1/3)$

$=\frac{80}{6561}=0.0122$

c. Find the probability that X will be divisible by 3 and at the same time it will not be divisible by 7.

$P(X=3)+P(X=6)+P(X=9)+P(X=12)+...$

$=(2/3)^3(1/3)+(2/3)^6(1/3)+(2/3)^9(1/3)+(2/3)^12(1/3)+...$

d. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent random variables with the same distribution as X. Find the conditional distribution of $Y_1$ given that $Y_1+Y_2=N$ where N is a given fixed positive integer.

1st attempt:

a. What is the distribution of $X$?

At first I thought it was a Bernoulli distribution with $P(X=1)=1/3$ and $P(X=0)=2/3$ with $X=1$ indicating a success and $X=0$ indicating a failure but as I thought about it more I am not so sure, because $X= \#\text{ of failures to obtain the first success}$, so it could take any value, not just $0$ or $1$.

b. Find $P(4 \le X \le 7)$

I am not sure if this answer relies on the distribution but my attempt:

$$P(X=4)=(2/3)^4$$

$$P(X=5)=(2/3)^5$$

$$P(X=6)=(2/3)^6$$

$$P(X=7)=(2/3)^7$$

\begin{align}
P(4 \le X \le 7) & =P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)+P(X=7) \\[6pt]
& = (2/3)^4+(2/3)^5+(2/3)^6+(2/3)^7 \\[6pt]
& = \frac{3^32^4+3^22^5+2^63+2^7}{3^7} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{27\cdot16+9\cdot32+64\cdot3+128}{3^7} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{432+288+192+128}{2187} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{1040}{2187} \\[6pt]
& = 0.4755
\end{align}

c. Find the probability that X will be divisible by 3 and at the same time it will not be divisible by 7.

So the probability X=3,6,9,12,15,18,24,27,30,33...

d. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent random variables with the same distribution as X. Find the conditional distribution of $Y_1$ given that $Y_1+Y_2=N$ where N is a given fixed positive integer.

I guess I need to figure out part a first..

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ we find the probability that $X=n$. Start at $n=0$. The probability that $X=0$ is the probability of an immediate success, which is $1/3$. The probability that $X=1$ is the probability of one failure followed by success. Thus $\Pr(X=1)=(2/3)^1(1/3)$. The probability that $X=2$ is the probability of $2$ failures followed by success. This is $(2/3)^2(1/3)$. In general for $n\ge 0$ we have $\Pr(X=n)=(2/3)^n(1/3)$. There are two closely related distributions that are called **geometric**. This is the less popular one,

Comment: Now that you know the distribution of $X$, I am sure you can do (b). For (c), hint, it will be the difference of two infinite geometric series. For (d), use conditional probability machinery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) has been dealt with in comments, and your revised **expression** for $\Pr(4\le \le 7)$ is correct. I have not carried out the subsequent arithmetic. The denominator $6561$ is correct, the numerator $80$ is not.

For c), we want the probability $X$ is divisible by $3$ minus the probability $X$ is divisible by $15$.

For divisible by $3$, we want $\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=3)+\Pr(X=6)+\Pr(X=9)+\cdots$. This is
$$1/3 +(2/3)^3(1/3)+(2/3)^6(1/3)+(2/3)^9(1/3)+\cdots.$$
The above is an infinite geometric series, first term $1/3$, and common ratio $(2/3)^3$. The sum is therefore equal to 
$$\frac{1/3}{1-(2/3)^3}.$$
Similarly, the probability that $X$ is divisible by $15$ is
$$\frac{1/3}{1-(2/3)^{15}}.$$
Finally, subtract.

For d), we want $\Pr(Y_1=k|Y_1+Y_2=N)$. The possible values of $k$ are $0$ to $N$. By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(Y_1=k|Y_1+Y_2=N)=\frac{\Pr(Y_1=k \cap Y_2=N-k)}{\Pr(Y_1+Y_2=N)}.$$
The numerator is equal to
$$(2/3)^k(1/3)(2/3)^{N-k}(1/3).$$
This simplifies to $(2/3)^N(1/3)^2$.

For the probability that $Y_1+Y_2=N$, note that the event can happen in various ways: $Y_1=0$ and $Y_2=N$; or $Y_1=1$ and $Y_2=N-1$; or $Y_1=2$ and $Y_2=N-2$: and so on. Each of these events turns out, after simplification, to have probability $(2/3)^N(1/3)^2$.  So $\Pr(Y_1+Y_2=N)=(N+1)(2/3)^N(1/3)^2$.

Finally, for the conditional probability we divide. Almost everything cancels, and we get
$$\Pr(Y_1=k|Y_1+Y_2=N)=\frac{1}{N+1}.$$
The conditional distribution of $Y_1$ given $Y_1+Y_2=N$ is (discrete) uniform.